# How to use DefinetelyTyped in a forked lib?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, definitelytyped

I had to fork libA just to update one of its dependencies. LibA does not have typescript definitions on its own, but do have an entry in DefinitelyTyped.

How can I match the DefinitelyTyped with my fork (since my fork does not match the same name and it is now @myrepo/libA)?

Before I was using:

```
import libA, {libAProps} from 'libA';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to keep the import unchanged but "rewrite" the module to your fork using the [`paths` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in `tsconfig.json`. This way TypeScript will still use `libA` for looking up the type definitions, but the actual code comes from your fork.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
    "paths": {
      "libA": ["node_modules/@myrepo/libA"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really get your solution... The lib I've forked is not a typescript one (hence me using DefinetelyTyped) so I don't have a tsconfig... Should I change this on the project using libA? If so, I should import both on package.json but change the entire project's compiler?

Comment: Yes these changes are in the project that's using `libA`. You would have to have your fork installed as well as the official types (`@types/libA`). And keep all your imports like they were before `import libA from 'libA';`.
The change in the `tsconfig` should make it so you can import your fork like you would import the original package.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a common problem, which I also encountered. My solution:

Instead of changing the package name (or scope), I publish my forks to a self-hosted npm registry:

I'm running a local [Verdaccio](https://verdaccio.org), using Docker Compose. The official npm registry `registry.npmjs.org` is configured as an uplink, so Verdaccio becomes a transparent overlay and I can locally publish builds of my forks and still fetch other packages from the official registry.

Because the package name of the fork doesn't need to be changed, DefinitelyTyped packages are still working.

Be aware that the solution is not optimal:

1. additional maintenance cost (but there may be more benefits, e.g. Verdaccio  is acting as a cache, accelerating future npm installs)
2. it is not quite obvious what packages or package versions are locally published forks.

Regarding 2., I established some kind of solution by manually adding a custom pre-release version to the original package version. Example:

- original version: `1.0.2`
- version of fork: `1.0.2-sbusch.1`

For further patches from my side that need to be built and published, I increment the last digit to `1.0.2-sbusch.2`, `1.0.2-sbusch.3` and so on. As pre-release versions get lower priority [according to semver.org](https://semver.org/#spec-item-9), `npm outdated` (which I run quite often) always shows the installed forks as available upgrades. (Note: `1.0.3-sbusch.1` could work better in praxis as it indicates the "pre-release of the next official, to-be-released version". Didn't tried this yet, though)

Other solutions I tried: `npm link`, `yarn link`, symlinks in `node_modules`. Had a poor experience with them, because they're skipping the regular build/publish/install workflow and you're using their sources, not their (transpiled) builds.

Any feedback greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. At least I would expect a comment when downvoting an answer where it's author (here: me) has spent some effort. ... OK, just noticed there's someone on a downvoting spree against me.